# Parse String to Datetime

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a equivalent on .net of the string parsing of Datejs ( http://www.datejs.com/ ) ?

I wanna do things like

```
// Convert text into Date
Date.parse(‘today’);
Date.parse(‘t + 5 d’); // today + 5 days
Date.parse(‘next thursday’);
Date.parse(‘February 20th 1973′);
Date.parse(‘Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00′);
```

Tks!

Comment: One option is always using this inside your page and passing a correctly formatted date in the post back.

Comment: Good question. I don't know a solution, and it can be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing in the framwork is [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx).  Unfortunately, these will only handle your last 2 cases, but the first 3 will not work.

There is no built-in way to do date manipulations using the standard DateTime parsing methods.  However, [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887189/fuzzy-date-time-picker-control-in-c-net/894365#894365) provides a utility class which will handle some of your other cases (or something similar), using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As Reed mentions, there is nothing like this built into the .Net framework.

Microsoft JScript is a .Net language that can be used for server-side processing; you might look into seeing if you can integrate Datejs that way.