# How to convert an NSTimeInterval (seconds) into minutes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nstimeinterval, seconds, minute

I've got an amount of `seconds` that passed from a certain event. It's stored in a `NSTimeInterval` data type.

I want to convert it into `minutes` and `seconds`.

For example I have: "326.4" seconds and I want to convert it into the following string:
"5:26".

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

pseudo-code:

```
minutes = floor(326.4/60)
seconds = round(326.4 - minutes * 60)
```

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that an NSTimerInterval is just a typedef for double.

Comment: See Albaregar's answer - it is a better way of doing this (more code but more flexible, maintainable)

Comment: That code is very expensive, however. For a quick conversion of a duration in seconds, this answer is better.

Comment: Please note that this answer will give you stuff like 1:60. Look at StratFan's answer which is closer to the truth. But remove floor and round and you should be home free.

Comment: Mick MacCallum's answer below at the time of writing this comment seems to be most updated and made by the way of using native API.

Answer (score 183):

**Brief Description**

1. The answer from Brian Ramsay is more convenient if you only want to convert to minutes.
2. If you want Cocoa API do it for you and convert your NSTimeInterval not only to minutes but also to days, months, week, etc,... I think this is a more generic approach
3. Use NSCalendar method:

   - `(NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)resultDate options:(NSUInteger)opts`
   - "Returns, as an NSDateComponents object using specified components, the difference between two supplied dates". From the API documentation.
4. Create 2 NSDate whose difference is the NSTimeInterval you want to convert. (If your NSTimeInterval comes from comparing 2 NSDate you don't need to do this step, and you don't even need the NSTimeInterval).
5. Get your quotes from NSDateComponents

**Sample Code**

```
// The time interval 
NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = 326.4;

// Get the system calendar
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the NSDates
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1]; 

// Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

NSLog(@"Conversion: %dmin %dhours %ddays %dmoths",[conversionInfo minute], [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo day], [conversionInfo month]);

[date1 release];
[date2 release];
```

**Known issues**

- Too much for just a conversion, you are right, but that's how the API works.
- My suggestion: if you get used to manage your time data using NSDate and NSCalendar, the API will do the hard work for you.

Comment: Definitively is a lot of workaround just to do a little conversion, but it feels confortable, modular and really flexible, vote up for this sample code @Albaregar.

Comment: +1 For a good thorough answer, however this code is quite expensive.

Comment: +1 ... one caveat. Be careful using this style of code if you need to round up fractional seconds. The default behaviour of -[NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:] can mess up in the scenario where the toDate component is 31.5 seconds (for example) ahead of the fromDate - the components returned will have 31 in the seconds field. There's an optional parameter of NSWrapCalendarComponents, but from the (limited) experimentation I've done with this, it wraps to the nearest second rather than rounding up or down. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: `%ld` if you are in 64 bit machine.

Comment: People who find this (like Nick Weaver) are going to think that code looks like it would be slow. It isn't. I'm doing a timer app and I just tested Albaregar's version against something in the style of Brian Ramsey (and others)... and surprisingly, even polling 100 times a second (which is tremendous overkill) on a relatively slow device (4S) there was less than a 1% difference in processor utilization.

Answer (score 44):

All of these look more complicated than they need to be! Here is a short and sweet way to convert a time interval into hours, minutes and seconds:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 326.4;
long seconds = lroundf(timeInterval); // Since modulo operator (%) below needs int or long

int hour = seconds / 3600;
int mins = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
int secs = seconds % 60;
```

Note when you put a float into an int, you get floor() automatically, but you can add it to the first two if if makes you feel better :-)

Comment: Awesome! I tried Ramsay’s code though it seem to be out by a second.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in your code but it wouldn't let me edit it to fix it.

Comment: I think your approach is best - simple, gets the job done, and "light" on the ticks.  Perfect.

Answer (score 29):

Forgive me for being a Stack virgin... I'm not sure how to reply to Brian Ramsay's answer...

Using round will not work for second values between 59.5 and 59.99999.  The second value will be 60 during this period.  Use trunc instead...

```
 double progress;

 int minutes = floor(progress/60);
 int seconds = trunc(progress - minutes * 60);
```

Comment: Actually just remove floor and trunk/round altogether. :)

Comment: @StratFan Can you please add hours to your answer?

Answer (score 27):

If you're targeting at or above iOS 8 or OS X 10.10, this just got a lot easier. The new `NSDateComponentsFormatter` class allows you to convert a given `NSTimeInterval` from its value in seconds to a localized string to show the user. For example:

Objective-C

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 326.4;

NSDateComponentsFormatter *componentFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];

componentFormatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
componentFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorDropAll;

NSString *formattedString = [componentFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:interval];
NSLog(@"%@",formattedString); // 5:26
```

Swift

```
let interval = 326.4

let componentFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

componentFormatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
componentFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .DropAll

if let formattedString = componentFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(interval) {
    print(formattedString) // 5:26
}
```

`NSDateCompnentsFormatter` also allows for this output to be in longer forms. More info can be found in NSHipster's [NSFormatter article](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/). And depending on what classes you're already working with (if not `NSTimeInterval`), it may be more convenient to pass the formatter an instance of `NSDateComponents`, or two `NSDate` objects, which can be done as well via the following methods.

Objective-C

```
NSString *formattedString = [componentFormatter stringFromDate:<#(NSDate *)#> toDate:<#(NSDate *)#>];
NSString *formattedString = [componentFormatter stringFromDateComponents:<#(NSDateComponents *)#>];
```

Swift

```
if let formattedString = componentFormatter.stringFromDate(<#T##startDate: NSDate##NSDate#>, toDate: <#T##NSDate#>) {
    // ...
}

if let formattedString = componentFormatter.stringFromDateComponents(<#T##components: NSDateComponents##NSDateComponents#>) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to create the string, adequately localized

Comment: This answer is way more "Objective-C" and useful than the accepted answer.  You don't need `switch` or `if else` statements with this. `NSDateComponentsFormatter` takes care of it all. Hours, Minutes, Seconds printed without any worry.

Answer (score 17):

Brian Ramsay’s code, de-pseudofied:

```
- (NSString*)formattedStringForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    NSInteger minutes = floor(duration/60);
    NSInteger seconds = round(duration - minutes * 60);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
}
```

Comment: This does not localize

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Swift version:

```
func durationsBySecond(seconds s: Int) -> (days:Int,hours:Int,minutes:Int,seconds:Int) {
    return (s / (24 * 3600),(s % (24 * 3600)) / 3600, s % 3600 / 60, s % 60)
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
let (d,h,m,s) = durationsBySecond(seconds: duration)
println("time left: \(d) days \(h) hours \(m) minutes \(s) seconds")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    NSDate *timeLater = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*90];

    NSTimeInterval duration = [timeLater  timeIntervalSinceNow];

    NSInteger hours = floor(duration/(60*60));
    NSInteger minutes = floor((duration/60) - hours * 60);
    NSInteger seconds = floor(duration - (minutes * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60));

    NSLog(@"timeLater: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timeLater]);

    NSLog(@"time left: %d hours %d minutes  %d seconds", hours,minutes,seconds);
```

Outputs:

```
timeLater: 22:27
timeLeft: 1 hours 29 minutes  59 seconds
```

Comment: its really perfect example to covert a date

Answer (score 5):

Since it's essentially a double...

Divide by 60.0 and extract the integral part and the fractional part.

The integral part will be the whole number of minutes.

Multiply the fractional part by 60.0 again.

The result will be the remaining seconds.

Answer (score 3):

*Remember that the original question is about a string output, not pseudo-code or individual string components.*

> I want to convert it into the following string: "5:26"

*Many answers are missing the internationalization issues, and most doing the math computations by hand. All just so 20th century...*

#### Do not do the Math yourself (Swift 4)

```
let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 326.4
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
if let formatted = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: timeInterval) {
    print(formatted)
}
```

> 5:26

---

#### Leverage on libraries

If you really want individual components, and pleasantly readable code, check out [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate):

```
import SwiftDate
...
if let minutes = Int(timeInterval).seconds.in(.minute) {
    print("\(minutes)")
}
```

> 5

---

*Credits to [@mickmaccallum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252412/218152) and [@polarwar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355572/218152) for adequate usage of `DateComponentsFormatter`*

Answer (score 0):

How I did this in Swift (including the string formatting to show it as "01:23"):

```
let totalSeconds: Double = someTimeInterval
let minutes = Int(floor(totalSeconds / 60))
let seconds = Int(round(totalSeconds % 60))        
let timeString = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
NSLog(timeString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 version

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
            func toMM_SS() -> String {
                let interval = self
                let componentFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

                componentFormatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
                componentFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
                componentFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute, .Second]
                return componentFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(interval) ?? ""
            }
        }
    let duration = 326.4.toMM_SS()
    print(duration)    //"5:26"
```