# how can i define NSTimeInterval to mm:ss format in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i define NSTimeInterval to mm:ss format?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189252/how-to-convert-an-nstimeinterval-seconds-into-minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189252/how-to-convert-an-nstimeinterval-seconds-into-minutes).

Accepted answer by Brian Ramsay is:

Given 326.4 seconds, pseudo-code:

```
minutes = floor(326.4/60)
seconds = round(326.4 - minutes * 60)
```

If you print with `%02d`, you will get e.g. `03:08` if either number is less than 10.

Comment: with "%2d" you would get " 3: 8", you want %02d instead to get the leading zero.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @progrmr; I haven't looked back at this answer in a while to see the imbalance.

Answer (score 30):

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 326.4;
long min = (long)interval / 60;    // divide two longs, truncates
long sec = (long)interval % 60;    // remainder of long divide
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", min, sec];
```

The %02d format specifier gives you a 2 digit number with a leading zero.

Note: this is for positive values of interval only.

Comment: just take the absolute value of the interval, then do the math so it works for negative values also.  +1 for good solution!