# NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: I have to subtract 1800 seconds from NSTimeInterval to display the correct value

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am pretty new to iOS and as my first major project, I am trying to write a Music Player app.

I am using `AVAudioPlayer`, which reports the current file’s duration as an `NSTimeInterval`. To display that in mm:ss format, I am using `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`. The most convenient way to do it was using the `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` method. However, for reasons unknown to me, the method adds 1800 seconds (30 minutes) to the `NSTimeInterval`.

Why is it doing that and how do I solve the issue more cleanly than subtracting 1800 seconds from `NSTimeInterval`?

I don’t know if it’s relevant, but my time zone is GMT+5:30. Perhaps it’s the unusual time zone that’s causing the problem?

Comment: This is conceptually bad, since that time interval is not a date in a calendar, and probably you're in a time zone that has a half hour offset from UTC. You should just use a format string and integer division.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to manually format the `NSTimeInterval` everywhere I use it? (!!)

Comment: why not write a function or method for that?

Comment: yes, because the NSDate is always GMT

Comment: you are manually calculating a timezone into it - works - but weird :D

Comment: May be there’s an Apple-sanctioned method of formatting a `NSTimeInterval` ?

Comment: @duci9y by "sanctioned", do you really mean "recommended"?

Comment: Um, yeah. Like Apple recommends you to use a particular method for something instead of something else that might come into your mind first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [how can i define NSTimeInterval to mm:ss format in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558995/how-can-i-define-nstimeinterval-to-mmss-format-in-iphone)

You calculate the hours and minutes arithmetically, and then just format those as an NSString. This will be quicker than playing with NSDate and NSDateFormatter.