# How to calculate time in hours between two dates in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I calculate the time elapsed in hours between two times (possibly occurring on different days) in iOS?

Comment: Another option is to use `NSCalendar`'s [`-components:fromDate:toDate:options:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) method.

Comment: I don't believe this will give you an absolute number of hours.  It will only give you a value from 0-24, where you have to rely on the components Day, Month, and Year to get the full time interval.

Comment: I tested this, and it does work just fine. With fromDate 1/Jan/2012 and toDate 4/Jan/2012 this returned 96 hours.

Comment: post your code Thomas? It doesn't work for some.

Answer (score 173):

The **NSDate** function **timeIntervalSinceDate:** will give you the difference of two dates in seconds.

```
 NSDate* date1 = someDate;
 NSDate* date2 = someOtherDate;
 NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
 double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
 NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;
```

See, the **apple reference library** http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/
or if you are using Xcode just select **help/documentation** from the menu.

See: [how-to-convert-an-nstimeinterval-seconds-into-minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189252/how-to-convert-an-nstimeinterval-seconds-into-minutes)

*--edit: See [ÐąrέÐέvil's answer below for correctly handling daylight savings/leap seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156213/40175)*

Comment: And what happens if the dates / times cross the transition for Daylight Savings?

Comment: @Abizern: Thanks, I wasn't considering those cases when I answered the question. I've linked to the answer by ÐąrέÐέvil

Comment: i have time slot like 4:50:30 , h:m:s i have to subtract this time from 12:30:20 how i will do this

Answer (score 91):

```
NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *d1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1340323201];//2012-06-22
NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:d2 toDate:d1 options:0];
NSInteger diff = components.minute;

NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit
```

Change needed components to day, hour or minute, which difference you want.
If `NSDayCalendarUnit` is selected then it'll return the number of days between two dates similarly for `NSHourCalendarUnit` and `NSMinuteCalendarUnit`

**Swift 4 version**

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let d1 = Date()
let d2 = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: 1524787200) // April 27, 2018 12:00:00 AM
let components = cal.dateComponents([.hour], from: d2, to: d1)
let diff = components.hour!
```

Comment: What value dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 accept ? i believe you have convert 2012-06-22 date to 1340323201. please correct me.

Comment: Not working for me. Got diff value as 9223372036854775807. Is it in milliseconds?

Comment: Swift 4.2. Instead of [.hour] you can use Set<Calendar.Component>([.hour])

Answer (score 19):

```
-(NSMutableString*) timeLeftSinceDate: (NSDate *) dateT {

    NSMutableString *timeLeft = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    NSDate *today10am =[NSDate date];

    NSInteger seconds = [today10am timeIntervalSinceDate:dateT];

    NSInteger days = (int) (floor(seconds / (3600 * 24)));
    if(days) seconds -= days * 3600 * 24;

    NSInteger hours = (int) (floor(seconds / 3600));
    if(hours) seconds -= hours * 3600;

    NSInteger minutes = (int) (floor(seconds / 60));
    if(minutes) seconds -= minutes * 60;

    if(days) {
        [timeLeft appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Days", (long)days*-1]];
    }

    if(hours) {
        [timeLeft appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld H", (long)hours*-1]];
    }

    if(minutes) {
        [timeLeft appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld M",(long)minutes*-1]];
    }

    if(seconds) {
        [timeLeft appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lds", (long)seconds*-1]];
    }

    return timeLeft;
}
```

Comment: No, do not do this. Not all hours have 3600 seconds. Not all days have 24 hours.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Does not account for leap seconds, daylight time savings. Please don't reinvent the wheel just use the APIs provided with iOS like NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout : It takes care of daylight saving, leap year as it used iOS calendar to calculate. You can change the string and conditions to includes minutes with hours and days.

```
+(NSString*)remaningTime:(NSDate*)startDate endDate:(NSDate*)endDate {

    NSDateComponents *components;
    NSInteger days;
    NSInteger hour;
    NSInteger minutes;
    NSString *durationString;

    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute
                                                 fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];
    days = [components day];
    hour = [components hour];
    minutes = [components minute];

    if (days > 0) {

        if (days > 1) {
            durationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days", days];
        }
        else {
            durationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d day", days];
        }
        return durationString;
    }

    if (hour > 0) {

        if (hour > 1) {
            durationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours", hour];
        }
        else {
            durationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hour", hour];
        }
        return durationString;
    }

    if (minutes > 0) {

        if (minutes > 1) {
            durationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", minutes];
        }
        else {
            durationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minute", minutes];
        }
        return durationString;
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Comment: it is not showing more than 12 hours difference . if i want to check some conditions at 23 hours , then how to get 23 hours difference between times ?

Answer (score 4):

For those who use swift 3 and above,

```
    let dateString1 = "2018-03-15T14:20:00.000Z"
    let dateString2 = "2018-03-20T14:20:00.000Z"

    let Dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    Dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    let date1 = Dateformatter.date(from: dateString1)
    let date2 = Dateformatter.date(from: dateString2)

    let distanceBetweenDates: TimeInterval? = date2?.timeIntervalSince(date1!)
    let secondsInAnHour: Double = 3600
    let secondsInDays: Double = 86400
    let secondsInWeek: Double = 604800

    let hoursBetweenDates = Int((distanceBetweenDates! / secondsInAnHour))
    let daysBetweenDates = Int((distanceBetweenDates! / secondsInDays))
    let weekBetweenDates = Int((distanceBetweenDates! / secondsInWeek))

    print(weekBetweenDates,"weeks")//0 weeks
    print(daysBetweenDates,"days")//5 days
    print(hoursBetweenDates,"hours")//120 hours
```