# Difference in hours between two NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate

Here I'm trying to calculate the hours between two dates. When i run the application, it crashes. Could you please tell me the mistake in this code?

```
NSString *lastViewedString = @"2012-04-25 06:13:21 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSDate *lastViewed = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:lastViewedString] retain];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"lastViewed: %@", lastViewed); //2012-04-25 06:13:21 +0000
NSLog(@"now: %@", now); //2012-04-25 07:00:30 +0000

NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastViewed];
double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;

NSLog(@"hoursBetweenDates: %@", hoursBetweenDates);
```

Comment: NSLog(@"hoursBetweenDates: %d", hoursBetweenDates);

Comment: It does not make sense to incorporate changes that solve your problem into the code of the question. After that edit your code wasn't crashing anymore, so I did a rollback to the original version of the question.

Comment: Turn warnings on in your compiler. There is a severe bug, and with warnings turned on, the compiler would have told you about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to calculate time in hours between two dates in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084341/how-to-calculate-time-in-hours-between-two-dates-in-ios)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think difference should be in int value...

```
NSLog(@"hoursBetweenDates: %d", hoursBetweenDates);
```

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 12):

Referring to [this answer of a mostly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104714/1665702) a better and Apple approved way would be using the NSCalendar methods like this:

```
- (NSInteger)hoursBetween:(NSDate *)firstDate and:(NSDate *)secondDate {
   NSUInteger unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitHour;
   NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:firstDate toDate:secondDate options:0];
   return [components hour]+1;
}
```

If you target iOS 8 or later use `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian` instead of the deprecated `NSGregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 3):

NSInteger can't be shown by using

```
NSLog(@"%@", hoursBetweenDates);
```

instead use:

```
NSLog(@"%d", hoursBetweenDates);
```

If unsure what to use look in the Apple Developer Docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265