# How to calculate time difference in minutes between two dates in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate time in hours between two dates in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084341/how-to-calculate-time-in-hours-between-two-dates-in-ios)

I am beginner to Objective-C, so I need your help in syntax making.

My problem goes like this:

I have 2 Strings, and I want to convert that into `NSDate` and then calculate the time difference between the dates in minutes.

How can I do this?

Comment: @EvanMulawski that answer is for Mac Os and not for iOS i think!! Since we don't have [NSDate dateWithString:@"....."] such thing in iOS

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/date-and-time/date-and-time-examples I hope this will lead you in right direction

Comment: @Bala That is trivial. Just look at the related questions on the right and you can find iOS equivalents, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575689/objective-c-calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates.

Answer (score 35):

1. Use `NSDateFormatter` to convert the date strings into `NSDate` objects.
2. Call `-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:]` to get the difference between the two dates in seconds.
3. Divide by 60 to get the difference in minutes.

Alternatively, you can use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to calculate the difference in minutes for different calendars by using the `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` method.

Comment: Here you go

- (NSInteger)minutesBetween:(NSDate *)firstDate and:(NSDate *)secondDate {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
    return (int)interval / 60;
}