# Getting the time elapsed as UILabel (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, custom-cell, uitableview

I want to add a custom `UILabel` to my cell showing how long ago an item was posted. Any good links out there for a simple how to?

I want to add a label to my cell in storyboard, assign it a tag of say **22** and then programmatically calculate the time since the user posted an item.

**EDIT:** I don't care about my `nil` value so I have changed my code to below.  Now can someone either point me in the right direction to adding a timestamp or throw me a bone?  Much appreciated

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

PFObject *group = [self.groups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
nameLabel.text = [group objectForKey:@"name"];
UILabel *usernameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
usernameLabel.text = [group objectForKey:@"creatorName"];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do not use an if (cell==nil) clause when you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:. The cell will *never* be nil.

Comment: alright that's good to know cool.  But back to my question - if i want a label with a "time since posted" metric how would i go about that? @rdelmar

Comment: @rdelmar in which document it states the cell will not be nil? Initially there won't be any cell in the tableView, there for the dequeue method will return you nil.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala, no, when you register a cell, the table view will create a cell from the class definition if there isn't one to dequeue. The documentation is in the "Table View Programming Guide of iOS".

Comment: @JackCowan I understand your question is different but your dequeue method should not contain `forIndexPath:`, it should be only ` [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]`. If you mention indexPath then no cell will be dequeued because when you scroll down every indexPath is new and it doen't have a cell initialized. This will only work when you scroll up.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala Your last comment is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @rdelmar the asker is not using a custom cell, therefore he is not registering the nib! he is using default UITableViewCell

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala The OP registered the class. It works the same as registering the nib , except the cell comes from the class definition instead of a xib file. The same applies if you make the cell in a storyboard.

Comment: @rdelmar :) I am unable to see where it is been mentioned that he is registering the class. Well if that is the case then you dont to initialize. Also,  my comment for `forIndexPath:` was right if you haven't registered xib or class. If you have registered then it wont return you `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

```
postedDate = // NSDate object of your postedDate
[postedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date];
```

This will return seconds between dates, then just use some math to get minutes

Comment: Alright so say im creating an object which then will be displayed on the home screen once uploaded, do i need to save that "postedDate" when creating said object or can i just reference "postedDate" after the fact when i'm formating my cells? @Andyy

Comment: @JackCowan yes you need to have reference to posted date to get the difference between the posted date and the current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strTime=[aryNewsFeedData valueForKey:@"created"][section];

 int days,hours,minutes;

  NSDateFormatter *formatter    = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
  NSDate *chatTime   = [formatter dateFromString:strTime];

  NSDate *now =[formatter dateFromString:resultString];

  NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:chatTime];

  days            = secondsBetween / (60 * 60 * 24);
  secondsBetween -= days * (60 * 60 * 24);
  hours           = secondsBetween / (60 * 60);
  secondsBetween -= hours * (60 * 60);
  minutes         = secondsBetween / 60;
```

Comment: good stuff man - so if i wanted to use that to create a time since posted UILabel in my cell, how would i use what you posted to do that- Oh and im using parse -- so would it be like NSString *strTime = [group objectForKey @"createdAt] and then all that? thanks @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

If you have your posted date as an `NSDate`, have a look at `NSCalendar`s [`-components:fromDate:toDate:options`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:) to get the elapsed time. That will give you the individual components (hours, minutes, seconds... whatever you're asking for)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSString *SomeDate = @"22 04 2015";
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];       //Remove the time part
    NSString *TodayString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *sdate = [df dateFromString:stringDate];
    NSString *TargetDateString = [df stringFromDate:sdate];
    NSTimeInterval time = [[df dateFromString:TargetDateString] timeIntervalSinceDate:[df dateFromString:TodayString]];
    int days = time / 60 / 60/ 24;
    _lableText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",days];
```

[date-and-time-examples](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/date-and-time/date-and-time-examples) And 
 [How to calculate time difference in minutes between two dates in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373911/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-minutes-between-two-dates-in-ios) 
Go through these links.

This might helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit). I believe that's what you're looking for.

Apart from that, when I did not know about the existence of this library, I made this simple class method that returns a formatted timestamp relative to the current time (works for unix timestamps). Just pass a unix timestamp as a string to it, and it will return a string with the relevant timestamp relative to current time:

```
+ (NSString*) getTimestampForDate:(NSString*)dateString {

    NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[dateString doubleValue]];

    NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar* currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [currentCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:sourceDate toDate:currentDate options:0];

    NSInteger yearDifference = [differenceComponents year];
    NSInteger monthDifference = [differenceComponents month];
    NSInteger dayDifference = [differenceComponents day];
    NSInteger hourDifference = [differenceComponents hour];
    NSInteger minuteDifference = [differenceComponents minute];

    NSString* timestamp;

    if (yearDifference == 0
        && monthDifference == 0
        && dayDifference == 0
        && hourDifference == 0
        && minuteDifference <= 2) {

        //"Just Now"

        timestamp = @"Just Now";

    } else if (yearDifference == 0
               && monthDifference == 0
               && dayDifference == 0
               && hourDifference == 0
               && minuteDifference < 60) {

        //"13 minutes ago"

        timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld minutes ago", (long)minuteDifference];

    } else if (yearDifference == 0
               && monthDifference == 0
               && dayDifference == 0
               && hourDifference == 1) {

        //"1 hour ago" EXACT

        timestamp = @"1 hour ago";

    } else if (yearDifference == 0
               && monthDifference == 0
               && dayDifference == 0
               && hourDifference < 24) {

        timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours ago", (long)hourDifference];

    } else {

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        NSString* strDate, *strDate2 = @"";

        if (yearDifference == 0
            && monthDifference == 0
            && dayDifference == 1) {

            //"Yesterday at 10:23 am", "Yesterday at 5:08 pm"
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yesterday at %@", strDate];

        } else if (yearDifference == 0
                   && monthDifference == 0
                   && dayDifference < 7) {

            //"Tuesday at 7:13 pm"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", strDate, strDate2];

        } else if (yearDifference == 0) {

            //"July 4 at 7:36 am"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", strDate, strDate2];

        } else {

            //"March 24 2010 at 4:50 am"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", strDate, strDate2];
        }

        [formatter release];
    }

    return timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method and give it the NSDate or (NSString of my date) of my item as parameter. (in my case, a message). Just remove the first bit with date formatters if you want to pass an NSDate. (I personally use the two methods separately)

```
+ (NSString *)dateDiff:(NSString *)origDate{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   // 
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];  // remove this is you want to pass an NSDate as parameter.
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];          // 
    NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:origDate];   // 

    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    double ti = [convertedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:todayDate];
    ti = ti * -1;

    if(ti < 1) {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_NOW", nil);
    } else  if (ti < 60) {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_LESS_THAN_MINUTE", nil);
    } else if (ti < 3600) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60);
        if (diff < 2){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_MINUTE", nil), diff];
        }else{
          return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_MINUTES", nil), diff];
        }
    } else if (ti < 86400) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60 / 60);
        if (diff < 2){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_HOUR", nil), diff];
        }else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_HOURS", nil), diff];
        }
    } else {
        int diff = round(ti / 60 / 60 / 24);
        if (diff < 2){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_DAY", nil), diff];
        }else{
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"REL_TIME_DAYS", nil), diff];
        }
    }
}
```

Here the localized string :

```
"REL_TIME_NOW"                  = "Right now!";
"REL_TIME_LESS_THAN_MINUTE"     = "Less than a minute ago";
"REL_TIME_MINUTE"               = "%d minute ago";
"REL_TIME_MINUTES"              = "%d minutes ago";
"REL_TIME_HOUR"                 = "%d hour ago";
"REL_TIME_HOURS"                = "%d hours ago";
"REL_TIME_DAY"                  = "%d day ago";
"REL_TIME_DAYS"                 = "%d days ago";
```

I just don't have the courage to replace them in the code above. :D

This will return a string that says " 3 minutes ago" for example, and works like a charm.