# Not getting correct date from NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am new in iOS programming and i want to get difference between two NSDate objects but i am not able to calculate correct difference as i am not getting correct date from `[NSDate Date]`.

Have a look at attached screenshot. I am not getting what i am doing wrong?

[image]

I have tried solutions from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084341/how-to-calculate-time-in-hours-between-two-dates-in-ios) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386190/3824808).

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: The reason why neither of those suggestions worked for you is because you are trying to format the date **BEFORE** you work out the interval. Get the interval first and then format the date.

Comment: @SASmith Check the screenshot, my question was that i am getting wrong data "2015-19-20" and thats not possible so it was not working but now i got it and it is working.

Comment: Your screen shot is about formatting not about the difference. It is a little misleading as your question is asking about how to get a time interval and not how to display it. `[NSDate date];` will give you the time right at the moment it is called and not a time difference.

Comment: @SASmith yes you are right that [NSDate Date] return current time as you are seeing log it not giving correct value and that was my question  "i want to get difference between two NSDate objects but i am not able to calculate correct difference as **i am not getting correct date** from `[NSDate Date]`"

Comment: I would consider renaming the question to be something about formatting the difference and not about getting the difference to avoid administrator privileged people closing it or flagging it as a duplicate :-) I hope you have solved your issue now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this itself only needed to replace

> `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];` with 
>   `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];`

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const NSTimeInterval difference = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
```

This returns the number of seconds between both dates

Comment: thanks for help but i was getting mistake in wrong format and i got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,This will help you to get the difference seperately:-

```
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [currCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:fistDate   toDate:secondDate  options:0];

int months = [conversionInfo month];
int days = [conversionInfo day];
int hours = [conversionInfo hour];
int minutes = [conversionInfo minute];

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d months , %d days, %d hours, %d min", months, days, hours, minutes];
```

Comment: thanks for help but i was getting mistake in wrong format and i got it solved.