# How to format myString into an actual time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and teaching myself. Right now I am trying to develop an interactive clock, but now I am stuck so I need your expertise. Right now it's formatted
into decimals to the 2nd place. I was wondering if it was possible to format it to a colon
instead of a decimal. Or am I just approaching this problem wrong. :(

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary    *)change context:(void *)context
{

if(object == _knobControl && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"value"]) {
    self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", _knobControl.value];
}
}
```

Comment: What units is _knobControl.value?  Is it a duration or elapsed time?  Do you want to show 90 minutes as "01:30"?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046991/formatting-seconds-into-hhiiss, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122883/ios-format-string-into-minutes-and-seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood your question clearly, so following code maybe help you, but I'm not suer:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", _knobControl.value];
self.valueLabel.text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@":"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have, eg, minutes, and you want to display 90 minutes as 1:30, use modulo arithmetic.

```
int time = 90;
int hours = time / 60;
int minutes = time % 60;
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", hours, minutes];
```