# how to get song length in minutes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, duration, minute

```
assetURL = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
NSLog(@"%@", assetURL); // get song url
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil]; // add song url into AVURLasset
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration; //get duration in second
int  audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration); // get song duration in seconds.....
```

in this code song duration get into second i need song duration into minutes how it is possible ... thanx

Comment: convert seconds to minute!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122883/ios-format-string-into-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: not working .. dont convert cm time to int and float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
NSUInteger totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
NSUInteger hours = floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
NSUInteger minutes = floor(totalSeconds % 3600 / 60);
NSUInteger seconds = floor(totalSeconds % 3600 % 60);

NSLog(@"hours = %i, minutes = %02i, seconds = %02i",hours,minutes,seconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 -(NSString *)trackDuration:(NSInteger)duration {
     NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
     return  [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:duration];
 }
```

This is the least mathematical route.

For the SpotifySDK I had to divide duration by 1000. Go figure.

Answer (score -1):

Convert seconds(int) to minute(double).

Comment: second(float) to Minutes (float)

Comment: i cant convert cm time to intger