# How to get a time since string from a NSDate object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, datetime, format

Basically, I'm getting a date time string from an API, and I want to show in the app that this activity happened '5 hours ago' or '3 days ago', and so on...

I am currently trying to get the NSTimeInterval from `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` method. And then converting the time interval to NSDate again using `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval]`. And then checking the interval to see if its less that 60/3600/86400/etc, to set the right format for an output NSDateFormatter object.

Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a easier/better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's much better to use [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) for this. It's designed for this sort of conversion.

```
NSUInteger desiredComponents = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *elapsedTimeUnits = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:desiredComponents 
                                                                   fromDate:activityDate 
                                                                   toDate:[NSDate date] 
                                                                   options:0];
```

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that something that happened, let's say, 4 days ago will be expressed as "3 days, 14 hours, 6 minutes", etc. I suggest using this answer from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/932130/591487

Answer (score 4):

Check out this project: https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

It is a category for NSDate which does this.