# how to calculate diffrence b/w two dates in terms of mins/secs

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

i hav a two dates of type nsdate and i want to calculate the diff b/w the two dates as a mins/seconds finally...

how can i do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Alexsander want to say you take this:

```
double difference = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2] / 60;
The difference is now in minutes.
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` has a `-timeIntervalSinceDate:` method.

---

#### EDIT

Therefore:

```
NSTimeInterval tval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2];
int sec = tval % 60,
    min = tval - 60*sec;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/category-on-nsdate.html

as you get the days you can convert into time.

But if you want exact difference , like if it is 1.5 days

you have to convert date into timestamp then find the difference

[iPhone: Convert date string to a relative time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902950/iphone-convert-date-string-to-a-relative-time-stamp)