# Can someone help me convert a dotNet statement to a objective-C statement?

Tags: .net, objective-c

I am not a dotNet developer and was trying to read up some documentation on the following method:

```
signDate = Convert.ToDateTime("6/22/2011 8:35:21 PM");
```

What would be an equivalent function/method in objective C?

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that this code converts a string to a datetime type object, isn't it?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902950/iphone-convert-date-string-to-a-relative-time-stamp

Comment: @Felipe Yes that is pretty obvious. And a simple Google search shows that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx however being a non .net developer, I do not know what a DateTime struct is in .net

Comment: actually, what you should have checked is the `Convert` class reference, as it is the class performing the conversion. It has a lot of examples on the date string formats and the resulting dates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also not a .NET developer, but it looks like you're looking for [`dateWithNaturalLanguageString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

`NSDate *signDate = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"6/22/2011 8:35:21 PM"];`

Comment: @milo: Your question doesn't mention iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should check out the [NSDateFormatter Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In particular, I believe you want the method `dateFromString:`

In addition, or for a quick overview, check out the [Date Formatters Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).