# How can I format this date properly in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have the following string:

"2011-08-31 14:12:24"

How can I format it so that it displays as "2h ago" if that is how much time has elapsed?

I have some code that works similarly, but not quite:

```
+(NSString*)toShortTimeIntervalString:(NSString*)sDate  
{ 
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:[sDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@"-0000"]];
    [df release];

    NSDate* today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *d = date; //[_twitter_dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSinceDate:d];
    [today release];

    //TODO: added ABS wrapper
    double res = 0;
    NSString* result;
    if(interval > SECONDS_IN_WEEK)
    {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_WEEK);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fw ago", res];
    }
    else if(interval > SECONDS_IN_DAY)
    {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_DAY);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fd ago", res];
    }
    else if (interval > SECONDS_IN_HOUR){
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fh ago", res];
    }
    else if (interval > SECONDS_IN_MIN) {
        res = fabs(interval / SECONDS_IN_MIN);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fm ago", res];
    }
    else
    {
        interval = fabs(interval);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0fs ago", interval];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already have your answer. What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Convert date string to a relative time stamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902950/iphone-convert-date-string-to-a-relative-time-stamp)

Comment: When I pass that string i get NaN ago

Comment: I think my date format is incorrect, not sure what it needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built an NSValueTransformer to do this. You can check it out for hints for your own code. https://github.com/billgarrison/SORelativeDateTransformer

Answer (score 1):

Check out [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It is a great tool for doing stuff like this. The [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html) can walk you through what you are trying to accomplish.