# Convert timestamp - IPhone

Tags: iphone, timestamp

i m trying to find out how to convert timestamp date and time ( format - 2012-06-14T13:15:21Z)  to display it on screen like '1 hour ago' / '2 days ago' / '2 seconds ago' etc. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What you have tried, and where you face the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Convert date string to a relative time stamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902950/iphone-convert-date-string-to-a-relative-time-stamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date1 = yourDate;
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];//Current Date
unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;                   
NSDateComponents *diffComps = [cal components:unitFlags fromDate:date2 toDate:date1 options:0];
[diffComps month] //gives you month
[diffComps day] //gives you day
[diffComps year] // gives you year
[cal release];
```