# How to convert timestamp to nsdate

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, nsdate

I have a timestamp as below. Its in a string format
"/Date(1402987019190+0000)/"
I would like to convert it into NSDate. Can somebody help me into this one?

Answer (score 1):

Use [dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:),

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Use this function to convert string to timestamp Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/932130/1868660

```
-(NSString *)dateDiff:(NSString *)origDate {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss VVVV"];
    NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:origDate];
    [df release];
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    double ti = [convertedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:todayDate];
    ti = ti * -1;
    if(ti < 1) {
        return @"never";
    } else  if (ti < 60) {
        return @"less than a minute ago";
    } else if (ti < 3600) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60);
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes ago", diff];
    } else if (ti < 86400) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60 / 60);
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours ago", diff];
    } else if (ti < 2629743) {
        int diff = round(ti / 60 / 60 / 24);
        return[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days ago", diff];
    } else {
        return @"never";
    }   
}
```

Comment: But i am receiving it as string in JSON response. How do I convert it into Timestamp?

Comment: "/Date(1234324324+0000)" timestamp string is not matching such format

Comment: 1402987019190  == Wed, 11 Feb 2009 03:52:04 GMT

Comment: Hi Subodh, The original date is 06/17/2014 12:06:59, but it seems after conversion you got some different date, Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood what you mean, you need to parse timestamp from the string with given format.
You can use regular expression to extract timestamp value.

```
NSString * timestampString = @"/Date(1402987019190+0000)/";
NSString *pattern = @"/Date\\(([0-9]{1,})\\+0000\\)/";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
 regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                        error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult = [regex firstMatchInString:timestampString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, timestampString.length)];
NSRange matchRange = [textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *match = [timestampString substringWithRange:matchRange];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[match intValue];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Your understanding was just perfect. But the thing is original date is 06/17/2014 12:06:59 and after conversion when we print it through NSLog i get this 2038-01-19 03:14:07 +0000.

Comment: Oh.. I think maybe your timestamp is not in seconds? Amey, do you know what time unit is in your timestamp? Maybe your timestamp is not from standard date (1970)?

Comment: The thing is that Unix timestamp of your date (06/17/2014 12:06:59) is 1403006819
You may check it here http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: The response says, its a JSON date format, it does not have as such unit. So in that case, is there any way to get date from this timestamp?

Comment: You need to know what your timestamp means. It seems that it's not standard.

Comment: Hi Alex, Finally i get it, the timestamp was in milliseconds so i had to divide it first by 1000 and then apply your code. Thanks for help.