# Date will not display correctly

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to make my date display such as "March 2nd, 2018 10:00pm". I tried "MM-dd-yyyy" and "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" but it seems like none of these combinations are getting the date I desire.The function to pick the date is sendRequest and it is using a UIDatePicker.
[image]

```
 func getCurrentDateTimeFromTimeStamp(timestamp:String)->String{
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:Double(timestamp)!)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm a"
    return formatter.string(from: date as Date)
}

 let dateCellVar = request.timestamp
    let dateString = dateCellVar.description
    dateCell.textLabel?.text = self.getCurrentDateTimeFromTimeStamp(timestamp: dateString)

class Request {
var timestamp:Double

init(dict: [String: Any]) {
    self.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double ?? 0.0
}

 func sendRequest(){
    print("HEY:")
    guard let user = currentUser else { return }
    print("USER: \(user.firstLastName)")

    if let da = dateField.text{
        print(da)
    }
    print(timeField.text)

    print(locationField.text)
    print(messageTextView.text)

    guard let pickedDate = pickedDate else { return print("pickedDate") }
    guard let date = dateField.text else { return print("pickedDate") }
    guard let time = timeField.text else { return print("time") }
    guard let location = locationField.text else { return print("location")}

    let db = Database.database().reference()
    let ref = db.child("requests").childByAutoId()
    let data = [
        "sender": user.uid,
        "recipient": recipientUser.uid,
        "name": user.firstLastName,
        "photoURL": user.photoURL,
        "location": location,
        "date": date,
        "time": time,
        "pickedTimestamp": pickedDate.timeIntervalSince1970,
        "message": messageTextView.text ?? "",
        "status": "PENDING",
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"]
        ] as [String:Any]

    print("HEYO")
    ref.setValue(data) { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            print("Success")
        } else {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Do not use NSDate. Use Date. (That has nothing to do with the question; it's just a good rule to follow.)

Comment: See: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Also: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your result, your timestamp is in milliseconds, not seconds. You need to divide by 1000.

You also have the wrong `dateFormat`. You want to use `hh`, not `HH` for the hour. `H` is for 24-hour time which makes no sense when using `a` for AM/PM. You should also avoid using `dateFormat`. Use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. Let the formatter give you a date formatted best for the user's locale.

Your code also does a lot of needless conversion. You get your timestamp as a `Double` and store it as a `Double`. But then your function to convert the timestamp you expect your number of seconds as a `String` which you then convert back to a `Double`. Avoid the needless use of a `String`.

Comment: dividing by 1000 did it but the time is still showed as 24 hour format

Comment: Did you change to `hh`? Is your device set to 24-hour time? This is why you really should use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. Then you get a format appropriate to the user's locale and the user's settings.

Comment: yes I changed it to "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a", the device is not set to 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ordinal day, you can use `Calendar` to extract the `day` from your `Date`.

```
let date = Date()

let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
let day = numberFormatter.string(from: dateComponents as NSNumber)
```

From there, you'd just code your date format with a `DateFormatter` and drop in the ordinal date you extracted above, like so:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM '\(String(describing: day!)),' yyyy h:mm a"

let dateString = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: date))"

print(dateString)
```

Additionally, the issue with your year probably stems from the number you're feeding it. [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate) is expecting whole seconds, so make sure you're feeding it whole seconds.

> init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval) Returns a date object
>   initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 by a given
>   number of seconds.

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37539469/4475605). Additionally, you may find [this site](http://nsdateformatter.com) helpful for formatting dates.