# Day of Week in Month (numeric). The example is for the 1st Wednesday in April

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i have a date in swift that i get from http call ...

Now i want to format this date like : 1st Wed April

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "F EEEE MMM" 
let now = stats.getData()
let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
```

This returns **1 Wednesday Apr** but i need to formate date as **1st Wednesday Apr**

Comment: title edit ....

Comment: yes i want to format the date like 1st or 2nd or 3rd Day of the date month

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordinary Date Format "13th June 2007" in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536082/ordinary-date-format-13th-june-2007-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this we need two formatters, one for the date and one NumberFormatter for formatting 1 into 1st etc. Note that to get the order of the specific weekday in the month we use the date component `.weekdayOrdinal`.

The date pattern also needs to be changed to E from EEEE to show the abbreviated day name and month needs to be MMMM to show the full month name

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "E MMMM"
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal

let now = stats.getData()
let day = Calendar.current.component(.weekdayOrdinal, from: now)
let ordinalDay = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: day)) ?? String(day)

let dateString = "\(ordinalDay) \(formatter.string(from: now))"
```

Comment: Day of Week in Month (numeric). The example is for the 2nd Wed in July

Comment: formatter.dateFormat = "F EEEE MMM" found this but return 1 wednesday Apr and not 1st Wednseday Apr

Comment: i edited my question the question that you told me didn't solve my problem

Comment: for example next week we have wedneday 8 April right ? i want 2nd Wednesday April

Comment: sorry there is a method to return the day name and month name in Italian ?

Comment: You control that by setting the Locale for the formatter, `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")`

Comment: and for make the first letter of the day and the month uppercase like 1° Merc Aprile

Comment: because in Italian locale there are all lowercase

Comment: @vaccaboia I can't change the locale for Italy, this is something you need to research further yourself. It's probably easiest to find a solution that fixes the result afterwards.