# .NET Equivalent to DateJS

Tags: .net, javascript, datetime, parsing

I like the different human readable strings you can parse with the DateJS javascript project (http://www.datejs.com/).  I was wondering if anyone knew of any .NET library that could parse simiilar strings in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give look to these questions:

- [Fuzzy Date Time Picker Control in C# .NET ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887189/)
- [Fuzzy Date Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822124/)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of formatting options for [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx).