# Format DateTime like StackoverFlow

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Fuzzy date algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822124/fuzzy-date-algorithm)
>   [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

Hi,

How-to format datetime like SO ?

1 minute ago

1 hour ago

asked Aug 15 at 15:00

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822124/fuzzy-date-algorithm

Comment: current datetime-post datetime. Then based on seconds, minutes, hours format the string?

Comment: Even earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Comment: Duped the eleventh question.  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is determine the difference in dates.

Use the Subtract() method on your `DateTime`.  It returns a `TimeSpan`, which is handy for your needs.

```
TimeSpan mySpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract( myPostedDate );
```

Then, you'll need to find the most significant non-zero time element.  If you're dealing with days, things are easy.  Smaller denominations require a little more work.  Code included.

```
TimeSpan mySpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(myRecorded);
string  myDenom = 
  mySpan.Days    > 0 ? "day" : 
  mySpan.Hours   > 0 ? "hour" : 
  mySpan.Minutes > 0 ? "minute" : "second";

string myOutput = String.Empty;

int myNumeral;

// if we're dealing with days, a format string will suffice
if (myDenom == "day")
{
    // HH - 24 hour clock
    myOutput = String.Format("{0:MMM dd} at {0:HH}:{0:mm}", myRecorded);
}
else
{
    // put the right denomination into myNumeral
    switch (myDenom)
    {
        case "second":
            myNumeral = mySpan.Seconds;
            break;
        case "minute":
            myNumeral = mySpan.Minutes;
            break;
        default:
            myNumeral = mySpan.Hours;
            break;
    }

    // add an s to myNumeral when > 1
    myDenom += (myNumeral > 1) ? "s" : String.Empty;
    myOutput = String.Format("{0} {1} ago", myNumeral, myDenom);
}

// myOutput now contains formatted string
```

Answer (score 1):

You may interest to port [jQuery's timeago plugin](http://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js) to C#

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm). If there isn't anything you like, you can specify it yourself.