# Readable date from unix time stamp?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, unix-timestamp

Starting out with an int variable unix time stamp (something like 1290341015), is there a way to get this into a nice human readable date string? The iPhone Mail app has the ideal display of date, where it shows the time or date in the context of the current time.

```
06:47       (a time today)
Yesterday   (received yesterday)
Friday      (received last Friday)
09/11/2010  (received more than a week ago)
```

Is there a way to approximate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)
- [Fuzzy date algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822124/fuzzy-date-algorithm)
- [iPhone: Convert date string to a relative time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902950/iphone-convert-date-string-to-a-relative-time-stamp)

This has been asked quite a few times before.  The final link is the iphone specific one, the others a bit more general.